# With the latest version of phantom(2.42.0) and scala(2.12.0-RC2) No implicit found for parameter ev:Nothing while querying the database

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, datastax, phantom-dsl

I am upgrading to latest version of phantom-dsl 2.42.0 and scala 2.12 and according to migration guide now I do not require to generate fromRow() method but while querying the database I am getting no implicit parameter found (compile time).

I tried writing fromRow method but still it did'nt work

My case class is -

```
case class Ball(matchId: Int,
                      inningsid: Int,
                      ballNbr: Int,
                      timeScore: Long,
                      batStrikerDots: Option[Int],
                      batStrikerFours: Option[Int],
                      commFormats: Map[String, CommentaryFormats],
                      .......
                      ......)

class Ball extends Table[BallData, Ball] with CassandraSession with CommentaryPrimitive {

object matchId extends IntColumn with PartitionKey {
    override lazy val name = col_name
  }

  object inningsId extends IntColumn with PrimaryKey with ClusteringOrder with Descending {
    override lazy val name = col_name
  }

  object ballNbr extends IntColumn with PrimaryKey with ClusteringOrder with Descending {
    override lazy val name = col_name
  }

  object timeScore extends DateTimeColumn with PrimaryKey with ClusteringOrder with Descending {
    override lazy val name = col_name
  }

object commentaryFormat extends MapColumn[String, CommentaryFormats] {
    override lazy val name = "comm_format"
  }

............
............

}
```

col_name are respective column names.

**where comm_format is UDT so I have CommentaryPrimitive** defined for that which registers a codec on how to deserialize cassandra data to scala case class and CassandaraSession provides implicit keyspace and session.

This is my Primitive code to register the codec -

```
override def cassandraType: String = {

            val format_types = CassandraConnector.getSession.getCluster.getMetadata.getKeyspace("matches_data").getUserType("format_types")
            val formatCodecCodec = new CommentaryCodec(TypeCodec.userType(format_types), classOf[CommentaryFormats])

        CassandraConnector.registerCodec(formatCodecCodec)

            format_types.toString()
        }

override def asCql(value: PrimitiveType): String = ???

        override def dataType: String = ???

        override def serialize(obj: PrimitiveType, protocol: ProtocolVersion): ByteBuffer = ???

        override def deserialize(source: ByteBuffer, protocol: ProtocolVersion): PrimitiveType = ???
```

but while querying I am not able to resolve this-

select.where(_.matchId eqs matchId)(...).one()(...) --> retrieving Ball object

... -> **no implicit found**

**with a new version of phantom-dsl it should automatically resolve Ball data but it is throwing error no implicit found.**

Comment: Phantom works with implicits, not with registered codecs. https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/develop/docs/basics/primitives.md#deriving-new-primitives-from-existing-ones

Comment: You're also using the rest of the API wrong, and name overrides don't help you at all. Worth reading the docs end to end first.

Comment: My whole primitive code is inside and implicit object @flavian .  Like this - implicit object FormatPrimitive extends Primitive[CommentaryFormats]

Comment: My primitive type is implicit only, I was using codecs because older versions of phantom did'nt  work well with UDT values. Appreciate your help will go through the docs .

Comment: You're looking for automated UDT support, or auto derived types, which are currently only included in a subscription version of phantom. That will be made public at some point in the future, however no plans have been finalised.

Comment: For now you'll have to implement your own, registering codes will not help, because phantom does not use the binary serialization of the Datastax Java driver.

Comment: I implemented on my own and it worked .. Thanks